# Convert a dfa to rule for a asterisk case

Tags: finite-automata, formal-grammars, regular-expressions, compilers, parsers

Here is a simple but very common grammar rule case in EBNF format, the `Statements` is a none terminal symbol and `Statement` is none terminal symbol:

```
Statements ::= (Statement ';')*
```

After converting this rule to NFA, and then do the subset contruction for converting the NFA to DFA, and at last get the dfa:

```
State0 -> Statement -> State1 -> ';' ->State0
State0 -> ε -> State0
```

The `State0` is the DFA's start state representing the none terminal symbol `Statements`, also it is the finish state.
From `State0` input `Statement` and traslate to `State1` and input ';' at `State1`,  translate to `State0`.
Also, `State0` could translate to self with the `ε`.

And after converting the above dfa to regular grammar following the algorithm in dragon book, i get the following grammar rules:

```
Statements -> ε
Statements -> Statement Extend_NT
Extend_NT  -> ';' Statements
```

It added the new none terminal symbol `Extend_NT`, but i want to get the following the regular grammars  which does not contain the extend symbol `Extend_NT`:

```
Statements -> ε
Statements -> Statement ';' Statements
```

So the question is that is there any algorithm could get the above result that does not contain the new none terminal symbol `Extend_NT`?

Or it is just a engineering problem?

Solved:
I have solved this by removing the extend symbol in parsing stage. For example, in LALR parsing stage, when to reduce a symbol, i can remove the extend symbol at same time.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I have detailed the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I'm a bit puzzled what is the motivation to translate EBNF -> NFA -> DFA -> regular grammar, but OK.

Comment: You can try to use some pattern-matching-based simplification rule which discovers this exact situation, and performs the required simplification.

Comment: @D.W. I am making a parser generator and the input is grammar file in EBNF format.

Answer (score -1):

Solved:
I have solved this by removing the extend symbol in parsing stage. For example, in LALR parsing stage, when to reduce a symbol, i can remove the extend symbol at same time.